# Printing a barcode Cell but also an adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have a macro in Excel 2013 as follows:

```
Sub PrntCells()
Dim rng As Range, rngArea As Range, strCell As String

Set rng = Selection

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
End With

'Copy each selection
For Each rngArea In rng.Areas
    For Each cell In rngArea
        cell.PrintOut Copies:=1
        cell.Offset(0, 1).PrintOut Copies:=1
    Next cell
Next rngArea


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
rng.Parent.Activate

End Sub
```

I am using an addin to generate the actual Code128 barcode for me and that works fine and looks like this:

[image: Excel]

I have it setup so a user can select a range of codes and run the macro, each barcode comes out on its own label from the barcode printer but they also want to get the barcode and the cell to the right of the barcode to be on the label it is the item description.

Is there any way of doing this? I am having difficulty in getting it to print both cells on the 1 label.

I would really appreciate any help I am no Excel expert and this is my first time trying to use macros in excel.